# Can't keep text on screen in css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Basically im using a basic typewriter animation to make a text based decision game and i cant figure out how to keep all the text on the screen. The text goes all the way of the screen with larger number and id like to keep in like a block so it can be seen as a sort of make shift dialog box.

All ive done to fix this is payed with some of the css numbers and nothing worked

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323&display=swap);

/* Global */

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
}

.line-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 500%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 2.10s steps(35) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(25) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 60em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter"> Hi my name is jack strope, and i will be assiting you today. First, we will be introducing the most important concept in the game. So answer this.... What is the best fruit snack?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two rules to align the vertical position of the class `.line-1`

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

If you delete the `transform` rule, you can align the item with the `top` rule.
I would recommend you to only use transform if you want to do animations.

---

You could also leave out the `border-right` rule because it's unnecassary in my opinion. Maybe you need it for the animation.